# Area 51: What is sort proposals by *Votes*?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, profile-page, voting

On the profile page there is a sort list for followed proposals. What is sort by Votes? Should it be renamed to Progress or Followed?

Edit: I fixed profile tab to be profile page. (sorry) and added this screenshot

[image]

Comment: where do you see this? You mention the profile tab but I can't work out what you mean.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/25652/george-bailey

Comment: I will add a screenshot

Comment: thanks. First, *love* the picture! I think that "votes" sorts the proposals based on the total number of votes the example questions have received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errm, it's a legacy holdover from the Q&A sites.  In this case, it's sorting proposals by number of followers, which isn't very useful.  I've replaced it with a "progress" option, to sort by total progress of the proposal.

Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

I think that "votes" sorts the proposals based on the total number of votes the example questions have received.

So if proposal A has 2 questions each with 3 votes (say 2 on topic and 1 off topic) that is 6 votes total. If B has 1 question with 5 votes, then A is listed before B.